# How do I use a prettify.js theme?

Tags: javascript, themes, prettify, google-code-prettify

There's [a set of "themes" for prettify.js](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styles/index.html).

How do I actually use them? Do I `<link href="">` to a selected "theme" `.css` file instead of `prettify.css` file or do I do anything else? What's the procedure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace the default CSS file with your theme's CSS file:

```
<link href="sunburst.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```